# List of pi camera settings that can be adjusted during recording

Tags: raspicam

I found the following statement in the picamera documentation:

> Several attributes are provided to adjust the camera’s configuration. Some of these can be adjusted while a recording is running, like brightness. Others, like resolution, can only be adjusted when the camera is idle.

Is there a complete list of settings that can and can not be adjusted during recording?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I've compiled a complete list of the attributes that can definitely be used when recording because I don't know them myself. I can say that [`resolution`](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/api_camera.html#picamera.camera.PiCamera.resolution) and [`framerate`](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/api_camera.html#picamera.camera.PiCamera.framerate) both can't be used because they involve re-initializing the camera. Almost everything else seems to be okay but there are odd exceptions (e.g. [`image_effect`](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/api_camera.html#picamera.camera.PiCamera.image_effect) mostly seems to work, but some effects don't operate on the video output).

I'm a bit hesitant to create a definitive list because it's probably yet another list that would become incomplete as things evolved ("this new feature isn't on the list - so it *can't* be used when recording, or it *can* and you just forgot to add it?"). However, I can say that every attribute that definitely *can't* be used when recording is active, has that fact clearly documented in the API reference. For example the following sentence appears in the description of both [`resolution`](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/api_camera.html#picamera.camera.PiCamera.resolution) and [`framerate`](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/api_camera.html#picamera.camera.PiCamera.framerate):

> ... the camera must not be closed, and no recording must be active when the property is set.

In other words, if you're not sure check the API docs (I know they're long and boring, but generally a search of the attribute or method name will have the API reference at the top of the results).